# How to add text to an arrow in GnuPlot

Tags: gnuplot, octave

Is it possible to add text to an arrow in gnuplot?

Lets say I draw an arrow:

```
set arrow from 0,0 to 1,1 head
plot(x)
```

Is it possible to attach this arrow some text ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Use this command:

```
set label "arrow" at 1,1
```

[More details on label can be found here](http://www.manpagez.com/info/gnuplot/gnuplot-4.4.3/gnuplot_259.php)
To be fair, it doesn't attach the text/label to the arrow, but places it on the graph. As you know where your arrow is, you can collocate that with the label though.